# bootstrap.styl breaks when parsing with stylus

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, stylus

I am trying to use stylus a css preprocessor with twitter bootstrap version 2.04.  When I download boostrap I run "stylus --css < bootstrap.css > bootstrap.styl" so that I can create a bootstrap.styl file.  However I get the following error when my browser tries to parse bootstrap.styl

```
ParseError: /Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/static/css/bootstrap.styl:1835
   1831|   background-position: -313px -119px
   1832| 
   1833| .icon-retweet
   1834|   background-position: -336px -120px
 > 1835| 
   1836| .icon-shopping-cart
   1837|   background-position: -360px -120px
   1838| 

expected "indent", got "outdent"

at Parser.error (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:166:11)
at Parser.expect (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:194:12)
at Parser.block (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:597:12)
at Parser.selector (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1099:24)
at Parser.property (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1013:47)
at Parser.ident (/Users//Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:970:25)
at Parser.stmt (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:546:25)
at Parser.statement (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:458:21)
at Parser.block (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:609:21)
at Parser.selector (/Users/user/Projects/node_tutorials/project/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:1099:24)
```

I've checked for additional whitespace and have even hexdumped the file and nothing appears to be wrong.  Can anyone identify the problem?

Comment: you won't be able to since Bootstrap uses MS filtering and Stylus can't parse it.

Answer (score 3):

@Jonathan is right. the problem is caused by filter

I found a workaround using stylus function `unquote`

just do a regex replace `filter: (.+)$` => `filter: unquote("\1")` to bootstrap.styl

Comment: Works perfect. Just a small note if you are using WebStorm, you need to make the replace string look like this: `filter: unquote("$1")` to actualy match the finding in the search string!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the indentation of the *entire* file? This sort of message can often be caused by an error located well before the parser sees something wrong.

Comment: In vim I higlighted extraneous white space, and I didn't see anything.  Is there another sure fire way to find the white spaces that are causing my problem?